# @username in comments doesn't autocomplete for some users

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comment-replies, autocomplete

When I want to address a specific users in the comment section for a question I use @username, sometimes after typing first letters of the username it shows up an autocomplete box but sometimes it doesn't show it up for another user.

I don't know the reason of these different behaviors! and whatever the reason is I think shouldn't be related to auto-complete feature because I just think this is a bug

Comment: @Anna Lear My question is different, I asked about the behavior of the system. the way it suggests autocomplete for some users and doesn't for others was question for me

Comment: My goal here was to link you to the post that describes in painful, gory details how comment notifications work. I did, however, miss that Reto already did that in their answer.

Comment: Yes it was very painful and I skipped it. But my critic is about the vague behavior of system and have suggestion for it, I think its better when i use @x.. system suggest me an autocomplete option; just it. this way i get sure the user will be auto-notified, I don't care when system do it if I forgot that, isn't that better?

Answer (score 3):

The `@` operator is used to notify a particular user about your comment. If this user is among those, who are already auto-notified (i.e. question / answer author etc.) you won't see autocomplete list at all or you won't see that user on autocomplete list.

Comment: You mean when it doesn't autocomplete I don't need to address him by @ operator? and he will get auto-notified without it?

Comment: Exactly! SE take care to remove from your comment, what is not necessary there.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, the name should auto-complete for people who both:

- Can be notified. These are the users who commented on the same post.
- Are not notified by default. The author of the post is notified by default.

Also, you can have only one explicit notification in your comment. So if a name does not auto-complete, this normally means that either:

- They are the author of the post, and get notified by default.
- They cannot be notified because they did not comment before you.
- You are trying to notify more than one user.

If it does not behave that way for you, you might have encountered a real problem.

There is an interesting exception to the above. Users who edited the post you're commenting on can be notified, are not notified by default, but their name does **not** auto-complete.

There are some other subtle aspects, e.g. in the case where the author of a post responds to a comment on his/her own post. For the full glorious details, see the answer to this question:

[How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Comment: suppose this comment for your answer, you mean for you there is no need to use @ to address me if you want to answer my comment? because I am the only person who commented here? I guess you should add this item to the items when the person is auto-notified, when he is the only person in the list?

Comment: Yes, I believe this will notify you automatically. This is what I referred to in the last paragraph about the author responding to a comment on their own post. I didn't want to repeat everything that was already in the extensive answer I linked to. This was closed as a duplicate anyway.

Comment: That article was very painful and I skipped it. But my critic is about the vague behavior of the system and have suggestion for it, I think its better when i use @x.. system suggest me an autocomplete option; just it. this way i get sure the user will be auto-notified, if system can't auto-notify a person because of items you said warn me about that. I don't care when system do it if I forgot that, isn't that better?